Smooth locus of an elliptic fibration forms a group scheme
I am reading this note about elliptic K3 surfaces. Let $\pi:X\to \mathbb{P}^1$ be an elliptic fibration with a section $\sigma:\mathbb{P}^1\to X$. Denote the image of $\sigma$ by $S$. Then all fibres of $\pi$ are elliptic curves with finitely many speical fibres as exceptions.
Denote the smooth locus of $\pi$ as $X'$. My question is why $X'$ is a group scheme.
My idea: There a group structure on not only every smooth fibre, but also every singular fibre minus the singularities. These group strctures might 'glue' into a group structurue on $X$. This is very rough.
What I've read about (page 218 in the note):

let $X_t$ be a singular fibre. The idea for the construction is to use local (complex, étale, etc., depending on the situation) sections through smooth points $x$, $y$ of a fibre $X_t$ and add the two sections on the generic smooth fibre. The resulting section then intersects $X_t$ in
a point $x+y$, which has to be smooth again.

I don't really understand this. I have several questions.

What does it mean by "local sections through $x$ and $y$"?

What does it mean by "complex, étale, etc., depending on the situation"? Is this something like singular cohomology and $l$-adic cohomology?

This reasoning just shows that the set of smooth points on a singular fibre has a group structure. How does this give the entire $X'$ a group structure?



For 2., I think the author is saying that there are several choices when considering topologies on $X$. One could endow the $\mathbb{C}$-scheme $X$ with several different topologies, e.g., honest topologies like the complex topology (considering $X$ a complex variety) or the Zariski topology, or alternatively a Grothendieck topology like the étale topology or fppf topology. The choice of topology determines what sort of sections we consider.

First, I recommend you have a look at Liu's book "Algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves", especially Chapter 9 and 10. I also recommend you have a look at the first few chapters of the book "Neron models" by Bosch, Lutkebohmert, and Raynaud. For your question: Let $E$ be the generic fibre of $X\to  \mathbb{P}^1$ and note that $E$ is a smooth proper geometrically connected genus one curve with a $K$-point $o\in E(K)$ (where $K$ is the function field of $\mathbb{P}^1$). Thus, there is a unique group structure on $E$ with origin $o$....

...Now, any smooth proper model of $E$ over a dense open $U$ of $\mathbb{P}^1$ has the "Neron mapping property". In particular, the group scheme structure of $E$ induces a group scheme structure on $X_U\to U$.  Proving this essentially boils down to the fact that elliptic curves do not have any rational curves and the fact that the exceptional locus of the blow-up of a regular surface is uniruled.
